# How to get the Longitude and Latitude from Address entered in text input, React native

Tags: react-native, geolocation, latitude-longitude

The subject refers. I have 2 input fields on my react native Map.
One is Origin / the second is destination. Now i want to get the address entered into the first input (origin), convert into longitude and latitude , then get the value from the second (convert to longitude and latitude) then show it in the marker.

How do I do something like this in React native. I am new to this.

**Edit**

This image, to get origin and Destination

[image: Screenshot-1620068609.png]

Answer (score 1):

Getting lat and long of a provided address is called geocoding:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview
you can read more from above,

Package for React Native:
https://github.com/marlove/react-native-geocoding#readme

To get the current location of the current User, you can use react-native-geolocation-services to get the devices current latitude and longitude.

and to get the distance, you need to use haversine formula:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#:~:text=The%20haversine%20formula%20determines%20the,and%20angles%20of%20spherical%20triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#:%7E:text=The%20haversine%20formula%20determines%20the,and%20angles%20of%20spherical%20triangles).

You can acheive the same using haversinejs package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine

Answer (score 0):

you need to call reverse geocode
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding

this package does a lot of the work for you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Comment: can i do a fetch to get the origin and destination as well? to get for origin and destination Latitude and longitude respectively?

Comment: I'm not sire what you mean by origin , reverse geocode takes long lat and returns addres, geocode api takes address and returns long lat

Comment: i will share the screen of the application. What i want to do, is to get the origin and destination longitude and latitude , so i can use them to show direction, thats all.

Please see Edits